# Spans and multisets

Tags: ct.category-theory

For some time now, I have been trying to draw a formal relationship between spans and multisets.  I have heard "tales" of how this might work, but no references.  Here is what I have come up with so far.

Consider the following.  Suppose you have a span in Set defined by sets $A, B, C$ with arrows  $f: B \rightarrow A$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$.  If we add a sense of direction, like “going” from $A$ to $C$, then this corresponds to a map in the Kleisli Category of the multiset monad $Kl(M)$ where the arrow is of type $h':A \rightarrow Kl(C)$.  Then, in the opposite direction, “going” from $C$ to $A$, you get a map of type $k': C \rightarrow Kl(A)$.  So, in this sense, a span can be defined with two maps in $Kl(M)$.  It would be good to have a single structure in $Kl(M)$ that encodes the entire span.  One guess is to consider the coma category $1/A$ of $Kl(M)$, where $A$ is the one element set.  In that category, the objects are multisets and the arrows are just the same Kliesli maps.  Note that morphisms in $Kl(M)$ are just integer matrices and composition is matrix multiplication.  This category has a dagger and so there is a natural way to consider $k'^{\dagger} = g'$.  In that sense, there may be “one” map that encodes the span, which is $k'$ and its dagger $k'^{\dagger}$.  That last part is not proven, so I don't know if it is true.

Is this going anywhere?  Have I made some bad mistake?  Is there a special structure in $Kl(M)$ that is going to do the job in a really succinct manner?

Edit:

After some thought, I came up with this.  We can encode each span "direction" inside one morphism in $1/A$ of $Kl(M)$, call this category $Com_KlA$.  The way you do this is you add a kind of duplicate of the information.  What we want to do is combine $f'$ and $g'$ in the same morpism.  You do this by using union.  Recall that in $Com_{KlA}$, the objects are multisets and set element is just a singleton multiset like $[a]$ for $a \in A$.  So, let's take a concrete example, because I don't know how to phrase it abstractly yet.  Rather than having two maps, $A$ to $Kl(B)$ and $B$ to $Kl(A)$, you have one map from $Kl(A \bigcup B)$ to $Kl(A \bigcup B)$.

Let:
$$A = \{a1, a2\}$$
$$B=\{b1\}$$
$$C=\{c1,c2\}$$
$$A \bigcup B = \{a1, a2, b1\}$$.

The span map is given by

$$f(c1) = a1$$
$$f(c2) = a1$$
$$g(c1) = b1$$
$$g(c2) = b1$$

Then

$$f'(1|a1> + 1|a2>) = 1|b1>$$
$$f'(1|b1>) = 1|a1> + 1|a2>$$

I am uncertain that we can easily take the union, but since the multiset monad is on set, that includes all sets, so the information is just $A,B$ and the set you are interested in is the union and this is natural.

It may be that you have to add these:

$$f'(1|a1>) = 1|b1>$$
$$f'(1|a2>) = 1|b1>$$
$$f'(1|b1>) = 1|a1>$$

Edit2:
...and there's the error.  You want to give all pairs, but you can't because you can't have

$$f'(1|b1>) = 1|a1>$$
And
$$f'(1|b1>) = 1|a2>$$

Spans give a witness to to how many times any pair was seen and that makes it fundamentally different from Multisets or their Kleisli category.

Someone has pointed me to multirelations and that looks like what I might have been thinking.

Comment: This is not what you're looking for, but [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S157106610480937X) seems slightly related, as it shows spans $M$ from $A$ to $B$ can be viewed (through an equivalence of categories) as "multiset relations", i.e. "multisets $M\colon A\times B\to\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ on $A\times B$".

Comment: Excellent, thank you @Emily

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Comment: _I have heard "tales" of how this might work_ — Do you have any links to where others might read these tales, in case they can intuit the details you are after?

Comment: @DavidRoberts actually, it was just chater on a forum, Zulip category theory.  It was one sentence that might be hard to find.