Spans and kleisli maps
When is a category of sets and spans just a category of sets and kleisli morphisms?  There is a link between spans and kleisli morphisms, but I feel like they are the same things.  I guess I am assuming that the base category for the monad is Set.  Is this only true for the multiset monad?  To see how we can have a category of sets and spans, just see the relevant nLab article.
I want to know if the morphisms in the Kleisli category of the multiset monad are equivalent to spans.  I want to know if the category of sets and spans is equivalent to the Kleisli category of the multiset monad.

Please do not post pictures, they are not searchable. And since this is a research-level site, you don't have to explain how spans form a category (a link to nLab is more than sufficient).

What do you mean by "a" category of sets and spans? There is only one (up to size issues). Are you asking whether Span is equivalent to a Kleisli category? If so, then yes, as every category is the Kleisli category for the identity monad on itself. If not, then please make your question precise.

See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/467978/spans-and-multisets
